# Does soundmanager 2 have the same trouble as html5 audio?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, audio

I am using [**Amazing Audio Player**](http://amazingaudioplayer.com/) to play music in my website. This tool just customizes the native html5 audio. But I'm facing some problems with html's `<audio>`. Specifically when my script calls `load()` function.

In Google Chrome's dev tools, I can see that status loops on "`pending`" when trying to get my mp3 file : [**screen shot**](http://f.cl.ly/items/3A1L412T3T3h0r0M0Q1d/1522704_10201419614555193_137170282_o.jpg).

Firefox and Opera run it as well, the problems is only on Chrome.

I am now going to use a javascript library : `soundmanager 2`.

But before, I would like to know if that problems also exists when playing sound using javascript.

Comment: make sure your server is respecting http Range headers on MP3 serves if you want webkit not to have to preload the whole MP3 to use it programatically. also, just curious, are you using an older copy of opera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used sound manager 2 on various projects, I think you should not have any problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will now start to use it. And I will give feedback.